# Prevent Hyphenation across lines + Enforce right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, hyphenation, geometry

My first question here, so it may sound rambling. So far I've found the answers about preventing hyphenation across lines and for setting margins, but I'm having trouble putting it together.

This is for my dissertation which has strict formatting requirements and which is otherwise finished. A committee member told me to stop the words from splitting across the lines with the automatically-inserted hyphens, but when I use the commands to prevent it, the words often cross the 1-inch right margin. I have the file set as ragged right (which is also required in my formatting). I used a template (designated as the document class) that already had the margins and most other formatting set appropriately for my university's requirements. Unfortunately since I didn't create that file, I'm not sure what other settings have been changed from the default. Before I tried changing the hyphenation, the margins seemed perfect. But when I try preventing the hyphenation (which technically worked), this problem with the margins arose. The document is very long and going through to discover every problematic word is not feasible.

I believe this is the line in the master template `.dtx` file that sets the margins, which I have not changed.

```
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,includehead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

In my own preamble, I use a bunch of packages, including `ragged2e`, and in certain places include the `\raggedright` command where needed. (I'm including my complete list in case a conflict between them is the issue.) I'm currently setting the `\righthyphenmin` command `=8` because that seems to be the smallest number that produces conservative hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[print]{nuthesis}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\graphicspath{{./figuresfolder/}} 
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.65}
\righthyphenmin=8
```

The template also includes these packages with the following settings, which I have not changed.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\newlength{\codeSkip} \setlength{\codeSkip}{2ex}
```

I have tried so many of the suggested answers and each of them produce some problem. I am not totally sure about how the template is working in conjunction with the files I've created or edited, which complicates my ability to apply the existing answers successfully. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Try using `\sloppy` in the preamble.  It changes the parameters of the paragraph optimization which will allow larger inter-word spaces, but produce less/eliminate overfull lines.

Comment: a different method for absolutely suppressing hyphenation is to set `\hyphenpenalty=10000 \exhyphenpenalty=10000`.  the first suppresses ordinary hyphenation, and the second prohibits line breaks at explicit hyphens.  if un-hyphenated words now extend out into the margins, you probably need to increase the "tolerance" and allow more stretch between words; `\tolerance=1000 \emergencystretch=2em` should help with that.  (this is stricter than latex's `\sloppy` setting, so should be a little tidier while still allowing additional flexibility.)

Comment: I'm quite surprised about the loading of `ltxdoc`, which is very strange for a dissertation. Of course I'm surprised also about not allowing hyphenation: it has been a common practice in typography for some centuries in order to avoid bad lines, particularly for languages with long words. A dissertation, even in English, often uses long words. Probably the committee member is afraid that wrong hyphenation is used; this is quite rare for TeX: what language is your dissertation in?

Comment: Thanks all, I will try some of those solutions to see which works best. The requests from committee members are due to their familiarity with different formatting. This might be the first TeX document any of them have ever seen. I am in psychology and only used it because I have a maddeningly large number of statistical results to tabulate. It would be very uncommon in my field, for example, to hyphenate the words "schools" across lines, so I understand why the committee member made the request.

Comment: Thanks to @barbarabeeton for the suggestion of the tolerance and stretch. I tried \hyphenpenalty alone before posting and had the same problem with the margins. I experimented with the settings settled on this: \hyphenpenalty=1000 tag:\tolerance=500 \emergencystretch=2.5em.   It yields more conservative hyphenation but allows for its limited use where particularly needed, without making the right column look too terrible. 
The dissertation is in English. I should mention, though that the template is from the mathematics department rather than tailored to my field.

Comment: I sympathise with your situation.  What the committee member is missing is that we use hyphenation because it’s the best we can do, and, as @egreg mentioned, we benefit from literally centuries of experience: the breakpoints in words are very carefully thought out to be as unobtrusive and understandable as possible (“schools” is never hyphenated, for example); and they don’t depend on the subject matter.  I’d also point out that from what you say, you have proofread your dissertation with normal hyphenation on, so removing is now is the extra burden.  How long is your dissertation, by the way?

Comment: @Carina The only sensible way to avoid hyphenation is typesetting ragged right.

Comment: @Carina -- i didn't notice before that you said "schools" was hyphenated.  it *shouldn't* be.  it sounds like some non-english hyphenation patterns are being used.  try issuing these commands: `\showthe\lefthyphenmin`, `\showthe\righthyphenmin`, and \showhyphens{schools}`.  the first two will stop after reporting; just hit return to continue.  the answers should be 2 (left), 3 (right), and "schools" (no hyphens).  if you get *any* different answers, the patterns being used are not for u.s. english, and more info is needed to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hyphenation can be suppressed more directly by setting `\hyphenpenalty=10000` to suppress ordinary hyphenation, and `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` to prohibit line breaks at explicit hyphens.

if un-hyphenated words now extend out into the margins, you probably need to increase the "tolerance" and allow more stretch between words;
`\tolerance=1000 \emergencystretch=2em` should help with that.

the result will still be ragged right, but less so than what results from
latex's `\sloppy` setting.  varying the values of these four parameters
after viewing the output can allow quite a bit of flexibility in order to
achieve an optimally pleasing result.

in a comment, the original poster reported that these values were chosen
after experimentation as yielding the most satisfying result:

```
 \hyphenpenalty=1000
 \tolerance=500
 \emergencystretch=2.5em
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for writing the final answer. To clarify for future users, \raggedright was already employed before I asked this question. The question was about modifying the standard ragged right settings to hyphenate words less frequently with more conservative settings. I am using package {ragged2e}.